# Using GroupBy on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

In a data-frame "df":
- I need to use GroupBy on multiple columns (col A,B,C,D),
- Need to use "describe" on one column (col E),
- Need to get rest of the original columns without any aggregation(col F,G,H)

Is it possible to all that in one line of code?

```
df5 = df4.groupby(['certification_ID','hco_id','measure_ID','measure_short_name',
'Year'], as_index=False)[['rate']].describe()

df6 = df4[['certification_ID',
        'hco_id',
        'measure_ID',
        'measure_short_name',
        'Year',
        'meastype',
        'prg_typ_id',
        'certification_name',
        'reporting_date',
        'result',
        'cv_vl',
        'numcase_cv',
        'datarcvd',
        'rcvd_oryx',
        'Month',
        'Quarter',
        'num_cv',
        'numerator',
        'denominator',
        'sum_num',
        'sum_den',
        'rate'
        ]]

df7 = df5.merge(df6, on= ['certification_ID','hco_id','measure_ID','measure_short_name','Year'],
                how='left')
```

Comment: please add the code you have already tried

Comment: You need a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: `Is it possible to all that in one line of code?` Very likely that yes. But we're going to need more information to provide further inputs

Comment: Just added the code that i am trying right now.